# How to design around Random.Next() limit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Say I have an object with 10 properties, all randomly generated from an algorithm based on `System.Random`, using a pre-determined seed, eg:

```
System.Random randomNumber = new System.Random(seed);
int prop0 = randomNumber.Next(x0, y0);
int prop1 = randomNumber.Next(x1, y1);
//...
int prop9 = randomNumber.Next(x9, y9);
```

This is all fine, until I decide to remove 1 property. Say it's the first property in my calls of `Next()`, now all result changes due to shifted call sequence.

- What if I want to maintain the result for other properties?
- Do I just generate the first property and discard it?
- **How should I best approach this problem in future to make updating my list of properties easier?**

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining what you're trying to do. What do these properties look like? How do you assign thheir value? What does _"result changes due to shifted call sequence"_ mean? Please read [ask] and show your code.

Comment: Yes, it's really complex to imagine what you expect to happen. What do you expect to happen when you remove one property?

Comment: If I remove the first line of `Next()`, all values afterwards will *shift* (I know it's a confusion word without context). I want to be able to run this program and get the same result for prop1-9. Of course there is only 1 possible solution (run a `Next()` but discard it), but I want to design my program to expect that, so I don't litter `Next()` everywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to generate the random value, but just ignore it's result.

Another option is to get rid of `Random` completely and use different random-generation algorithm. What I'm imagining is having function `f(seed, value)`, that returns "pseudorandom" value based on `seed` and `value`, but which is repeatable.

This way, each property will have `value` associated with it and it's random equivalent will be independent of other value's random equivalents.

Algorithm I made back then [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161336/how-to-generate-random-numbers-without-making-new-random-objects/228808#228808) could be used as such function. If you just use x value, and change the last line to have `from` and `to` instead of `0` to `3`, then it could be used like:

```
int prop0 = RandomX.Generate(seed, 0x45F6C854, x0, y0);
int prop1 = RandomX.Generate(seed, 0x96F4DC41, x1, y1);
//...
int prop9 = RandomX.Generate(seed, 0xFE840301, x9, y9);
```

So if you remove or add a property, it won't affect others. This also works if you are generating the numbers all across your code, so you don't have to keep tabs on generation of every value.

Or you could use something like

```
int prop0 = RandomX.Generate(globalSeed, objectSeed, propertySeed, from, to);
```

The combination of 3 seeds would produce "pseudorandom" value in range `from` .. `to`

The Generate algorithm might looks something like :

```
public static uint bitRotate(uint x)
{
    const int bits = 16;
    return (x << bits) | (x >> (32 - bits));
}

public static UInt32 Generate(int seed1, int seed2, int seed3)
{
    // simple "hashing" algorithm
    UInt32 num = 1;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        // multiply by prime numbers
        num = num * 119 + (uint)seed1;
        num = bitRotate(num);
        num = num * 541 + (uint)seed2;
        num = bitRotate(num);
        num = num * 809 + (uint)seed3;
        num = bitRotate(num);
        num = num * 673 + (uint)i; // not sure if necessary
        num = bitRotate(num);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Just add conversion from full `uint` range number to `from` .. `to` range.

Comment: Your algorithm looks cool, reminds me of xxhash (which I use to hash the seed to avoid repeat patterns over 1-nth seeds). But I am not certain how random your algorithm is across 1-nth seeds?

Comment: What do you mean by "1-nth seeds" ?

Comment: I mean there are 2 level of randomness. (1) in terms of using a single seed and taking 1-nth `Next()`. (2) in terms of using 1-n as seed values and taking 1st `Next()` for each. My bigger requirement includes both. So I ended up doing `System.Random(Hash(seed))` as `System.Random` doesn't meet the 2nd requirement.

Comment: Anyway I think that's besides the point of my original question. Could you explain `RandomX.Generate(seed, 0x45F6C854, x0, y0)`, or how is it different from a similar hash function?

Comment: So you are saying that you have seed. From that seed you take n-th value and use that as as seed to take m-th value for specific property? If yes, then my approach makes even more sense, because it can be expanded to multiple "seeds" quite easily.

Comment: @bitinn It isn't. It actually is form of hash function. Juts fine-tuned to use basic ints instead of blobs of bytes and produce nice pseudorandom output.

Comment: How do you use those 3 seeds exactly? I may need your code for `RandomX.Generate` to fully understand. `xxhash` is also very simple in terms of the algorithm itself, but one accepts 1 seed.

Comment: OK you convince me hash function is the way to go, I will see if anyone else have better suggestions. For now I will it as the answer :)

Comment: @bitinn You shouldn't accept the answer if you are not sure. It might stop other people from trying to answer.

Comment: well you are right, as my question indeed ask for a way to workaround system.random limit but we end up replacing it whole sale.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating and discarding the first property, you may discard the first randomly generated number.

I cannot imagine what you are going to achieve. If all properties are randomly generated integers, why not saving them all together in a property of type `List<int>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the values for a single objects, then probably including the values in the source is the best option. This will make the values independent from anything else (e.g. different RNG implementation).

If you generate values for many objects (and pre-generating is not an option), then you certainly have to discard every first value.
Probably writing a factory function keeping all track of all changes will be the best idea.

If you foresee that this is an issue you will have for many object classes, you may want to implement an even more general solution: e.g. a map `field` to `number of next calls`.
But that would be a bit too much, imho.